# How to properly insert a link to a template in WordPress?

Tags: php, templates, html, links

I am used to creating websites outside of wordpress just using HTML, CSS and JS. Normally if I want to create a link to a page, about-us.html, I simply add:

```
<a href="/about-us.html">About Us</a>
```

I have an HTML based template which I converted to wordpress theme via FTP. If I want to accomplish the same thing am I just supposed to reference about-us.php like:

```
<a href="/about-us.php">About Us</a>
```

Where about-us.php is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: About Us
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Besa
 * @since Besa HTML5 3.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php include('/about.html');?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Is this all that is needed? Should I be copy and pasting the HTML instead of using the include statement? Do I have to create a new page in the wordpress editor? Do I have to select a PAge Attribute Template, and if so why?

Thanks!

EDIT: When I try my method I just get an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/besa/public_html/about-us.php on line 10"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress doesn't work that way. In WordPress, none of the posts or pages that you visit actually *exist* anywhere on the disk. The content is grabbed from database and then the template files are filled with them and sent to browser.

In your case, you should create a file name `about-us.php` instead of `about-us.html` and then include it in your template by using this:

```
get_template_part('path/to/this/file/about-us.php');
```

Now you will be able to create a page from admin panel and use this file as its template.

As for your questions about link... Again you shouldn't directly link to a PHP file, because it simply won't work. If you access a PHP file directly, it doesn't load WordPress's engine when it is loading.

To do so, you should use the slug. Create a page, write down its slug, and then create a dynamic link in your PHP template like this:

```
<?php echo site_url('/some-path/slug-goes-here'); ?>
```

The above function with append `/some-path/slug-goes-here` to your site's URL and output it, which would be your page's link.

Comment: Okay, I'm still struggling a bit. 

Step 1: I created a blank php file called about-us.php in my specific theme folder which has only 1 line of code in it - "<?php get_template_part('/wp-content/themes/Besa/about-us.php'); ?>" 

Step 2: I created a page by going to add page and I called it "About Us" - but  I don't see any new template options? 

Also, by slug do you mean the permalink: "http://www.besa.com/about-us/" that pops up in the page editor?

Comment: @MatthewSirkin 1) The path should be relative to your theme's directory. For example, if the file is directly in the theme's folder, the path is simply `about-us.php`. 2) Your template's name should start with `page-` if you want WordPress to find it. For example, `page-about-us.php`, and then you can use `get_template_part(...);` in this file. 3) Yes, by slug I meant the permalink, but without the besa.com.

Comment: @MatthewSirkin Also remember this very important note: You can not access any of your PHP files inside your template directly. It will trigger a fatal error. Instead you should use them as templates to create pages in the admin panel.

Comment: Okay, 1) understood 2) okay so am I creating 2 php files then? One called `about-us.php` which has the content of what I want to appear - and one called `page-about-us.php` which includes `get_template_part('about-us.php');`? I think my mental block lies in not understanding templates or template directories.. Is there a place to read about what these terms mean? 3) understood.

Comment: @MatthewSirkin Yes you can create 2 files, but you can directly add `about-us.php` content inside the `page-about-us.php` if you wish. You can read more about template hierarchy at [WordPress's Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) or at [WPhierarchy.com](http://wphierarchy.com).

Comment: Okay sounds good, I will read up. Should I be copying the `page.php` files general format when I make `page-about-us.php` Or should it just be a blank file with either `get_template_part('about-us.php');` and whatever other content? And can i be including `get_header()` and `get_footer() in this file as well? Thanks for all the help

Comment: @MatthewSirkin You can make a copy of `page.php`, change its name and header,then add extra contents to it. It's better to do this since the header must exist in page templates ( I mean the header that contains name and description, not `get_header()` ). You can include anything you wish in your newly created template. Everything will work fine inside that template.

Comment: It works! Everything loaded except the images. My image sources were all of the format `src="assets/images/image.png"` They are trying to reference `besa.com/about-us/assets/images/image.png`. It works if I change the html to be `/assets/images/image.png` to search the root, or `../assets/images/image.png` to go up one level, but why does it default to looking for an `about-us` folder? Also, is this considered a related question or should I start a new question thread? (I'm new)

Comment: @MatthewSirkin If you don't use a forward slash `/`, browser will look inside the current URL. If you use a slash, browser will look inside the ROOT URL, which would be your domain. What you are experiencing is normal. You can take a look at [post thumbnail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) feature, and ask a new question if needed.

Comment: Ah, all is clear now. Thank you. I wish i could upvote the comments to let people know what was helpful, but I guess I need more rep for that. Greatly appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a page from WordPress Admin called "**About Us**". Then choose the page template from the right sidebar of the "About Us" page under "**Page Attributes**" section. Then use the following code in any of your template files where you want to create a link to "About Us" page.

```
<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/about-us
```

**Note that "about-us" is the page slug**

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'/about.html'; ?>
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?